# zsh: permission denied: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m MacOS

Tags: macos, python-3.6, zsh

Python3.6 are installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m

But `>>python3.6` does not recognize

Try: `>>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m`

Get: `zsh: permission denied: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install python3.6:

```
brew unlink python

brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

Answer (score -1):

If you installed from [python.org](http://python.org) using the .pkg file, it should have symlinked:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

*(check this by `ls -Alh /usr/local/bin | grep "python3.6"`).*

If the symlink doesn't exist you can create it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

---

If the symlink *does* exist but calling `python3.6` still doesn't work then check that `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH with `echo $PATH | grep "/usr/local/bin"`.

If you don't see `:/usr/local/bin:` highlighted in the output you need to add this directory to your path in your `~/.zshrc` file, with the following:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' >> ~/.zshrc
```

be sure to either open a new terminal once you've saved your `.zshrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` it.